# Is it possible to reclaim 'Passenger Service Charge' in BKK if you don't leave the airport?

Tags: bangkok, tax-refunds

I fly into BKK at 23:10. I then have a flight the next morning leaving at 11:10.

I therefore plan on not leaving the airport/clearing immigration. One of my charges on my ticket is the Thailand 'Passenger Service Charge'.

Is this an airport tax and can I reclaim it?

Comment: Can you explain your reasoning behind why you think you might be able to reclaim it? I would have thought that since you will use passenger services (i.e. the terminal facilities) then you would naturally have to pay the charge.

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was simply another name for a departure tax (that goes to the government). If that were the case then I believe at least in some countries if you are simply connecting you do not have to pay.

Comment: oh, ok‍‌‍‌‍‌‍‌‍

Comment: Based on [this article](http://www.passengerterminaltoday.com/viewnews.php?NewsID=43182), it appears the charge is an airport fee to cover the expenses of operating the airport. I don't see why they'd let you reclaim it, because you are, in fact, using the airport's facilities.

Comment: This makes it seem as though I shouldn't be paying it, http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/thai-airways-royal-orchid-plus/824504-do-i-have-pay-tg-thb700-ts-tax.html. No idea still however how to reclaim it or prove that I never left the airport...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are your tickets separate or one booking?

If they are two different tickets, then the Passenger Service Charge applies because you are technically / legally originating from Bangkok for the second one.  The fact that you arrived in Bangkok only 12 hours earlier and did not leave the transit lounge does not negate this aspect.

If you have a single ticket and Bangkok is just a layover, then the airline should not have charged the fee and you need to contact them about refunding the incorrect charge.

Comment: They were separate bookings. Fortunately the charge isn't very much money.